# Manter dimensão de imagem dentro de div com flexbox

Tags: css

Tenho uma `div`com `display: flex` e dentro desta `div` existe uma image com dimensão de `670x227 (natural)`, pelo fato de ela estar dentro de uma `div` com  `flexbox` ela é "redimensionada" na horizontal para preencher o espaço completo, sendo assim ela "distorce" ficando com `732x227`, tentei usar `flex-shrink` e `width` para mante-la com a proporção original e até agora não tive sucesso.

O CSS:

```
.media-objects {
    display: flex;
    flex-direciton: column;
}

.media-objects .image {
    width: 100%;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

Estou utilizando o framework css [`bulma`](http://bulma.io/)

Comment: Um Fiddle e o HTML utilizado poderia ajudar a responder melhor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na verdade o que acontece é que por *default* todo filho de um pai com `display:flex` tende a se expandir para ocupar toda a altura do pai caso o `flex-direction` se `row`, ou ocupar toda a largura caso o `flex-direction` seja `column`

Para resolver isso vc tem que ajustar o "alinhamento" inicial do filho que por *default* é `stratch`. No seu caso como o `flex-direction` é `colum` vc tem que configurar o filho para não expandir na horizontal, para isso vc determina que ele deve ficar a esquerda com `align-self: flex-start`, assim ele só ocupa a própria largura, e não a largura do pai.

Veja no exemplo como fica:

```css
.media-objects {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 598px;
    height: 160px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.media-objects .image {
    align-self: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div class="media-objects ">
    Nesse exemplo mudamos o valor inicial do align de stratch para flex-start
    <img class="image" src="http://unsplash.it/100/100" alt="">
</div>
<div class="media-objects ">
    O valor inicial do align e do justify é sempre stratch
    <img class="" src="http://unsplash.it/100/100" alt="">
</div>
```

---

**OBS:** Se o seu pai fosse com `flex-direction: row` (que é o valor *default*)

```css
.media-objects {
    display: flex;
    width: 598px;
    height: 160px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.media-objects .image {
    align-self: flex-start
}
```

```html
<div class="media-objects ">
    valor inicial do align de stratch para flex-start
    <img class="image" src="http://unsplash.it/100/100" alt="">
</div>
<div class="media-objects ">
    com o valor default stratch
    <img class="" src="http://unsplash.it/100/100" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para manter uma `div` com um `background-image` responsivo e na proporção, você deve fazer o seguinte.

Digamos que você tem uma imagem com o tamanho de 2000 x 1250, e quer manter essa proporção em qualquer tamanho de tela ou em qualquer espaço:

A formula que você deve usar é `(altura / largura) * 100`, então temos: `(1250 / 2000) * 100 = 62.5`.

Esse valor deve ser definido como porcentagem no `padding-bottom` da div que irá ter a imagem de fundo, mas você não deve passar nenhuma altura, deixe como `0`.

Depois é só definir o `background-size` como `cover` para manter a imagem do mesmo tamanho da `div`.

Veja o exemplo abaixo funcionando em https://jsfiddle.net/diancabral/mhfb24q2/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="img__box">

    <div class="img__src"></div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.img__box {

    float: left;

    width: 50%;

}

.img__src {

    float: left;

    /* Deve pegar a largura do elemento pai */
    width: 100%;

    /* O height é zero mesmo, a altura vai ser definida no padding-bottom */
    height: 0;

    /* Aqui você deve colocar o resultado da formula como porcentagem */
    padding-bottom: 62.5%;

    background: url(http://folhanobre.xyz/2015/09/Paisagem_imagem_linda_-52.jpg);

    background-size: cover;

}
```

Se você quiser fazer isso com imagens em pé, é só inverter a formula e calcular `(largura / altura) * 100`.